# How to make my bot react to a specific message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, command, bots

I created a command for my discord bot allowing to react to messages, but I do not know how to make it react to a specific message. My try was unsuccessful. What did I do wrong?

Here is my code:

```
const [name, messageID] = args.join(' ').split(' ')
if (!name) return message.channel.send("Veuillez indiquer le nom de l'emoji.")
if (!messageID) return message.channel.send("Veuillez indiquer l\'ID du message.")
const reactionEmoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === name);
(messageID).react(reactionEmoji)
```

Comment: Why do you `.join(' ')` the `args` array to a string and then `.split(' ')` back to an array again? It doesn't really make sense. How do you want to `react()` to a string? You should get the message with that `messageID` first.

Comment: Please do not edit-delete questions which you no longer consider worthwhile. It makes searching this site harder. Either just outright delete your question, or – if you lack the privileges – message one of the mods to close it (and then subsequently delete).

Answer (score -1):

You didn't clearify if `args` is an `Array` or `String`
Also `.join(' ').split(' ')` is useless because it'll return whatever it was (No Change)
And you can't only fetch the message from the `MessageID` You'll also need the `ChannelID`
French: Et vous ne pouvez pas seulement récupérer le message du `MessageID` Vous aurez également besoin du `ChannelID`

Try something like this:
French: Essayez quelque chose comme ça

```js
let name, messageID, channelID;
if(typeof(args) != string){
    //args is an array (Might be number but let's forget that part)
    //args est une array (Peut-être un numéro mais oublions cette partie)
    [name, messageID, channelID] = args;
}else{
    //args is an String
    //French: args est une string
    [name, messageID, channelID] = args.split(' '); //No need to join()
}
if(!name){ return message.channel.send("Enter name") }
if(!messageID){ return message.channel.send("Enter message ID") }
if(!channelID){ return message.channel.send("Enter Channel ID") }
//This line is from your code
//French: Cette ligne provient de votre code
const reactionEmoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === name);
//You have to fetch the message before using it
const reactChannel = await client.channels.cache.get(channelID);
if(!reactChannel){ return message.channel.send("Channel not accessable") }
let reactMessage = await reactChannel.messages.fetch("701574160211771462");
//Then finally
reactMessage.react(reactionEmoji);
```

Si vous ne parvenez pas à comprendre l'anglais, essayez d'utiliser Google Translate

Comment: Thanks really, I do this.